# Expanding UITableViewCell not working as intended

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface

After browsing the internet for various different ways of making expanding/collapsible UITableViewCells, I started my approach earlier today.

I have an array that holds the state of each row in my UITableView(COLLAPSED=0, EXPANDED=1). When the expand button is clicked, I reverse the state in the array, and call reloadSection on whichever section needs to be updates.

In my delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath, I check to see whether the cell should be expanded or not and return the proper height. The problem I am facing is that my cell does indeed expand, but instead of showing my content hid underneath(I made the cell much bigger with extra info underneath shortened it in IB, and enabled clip subviews to fix the cell overlap), it shows two other grouped UITableViewCells with a similar background as mine and throws the positioning of some labels/buttons off.

I am including pictures of what it looks like normally and expanded. I have gone through the code and it all looks okay, I think there may be a setting I need to change in order for this to render properly.

[image: Collapsed]

[image: Expanded]

[image: Collapsed Cell in IB]

[image: Expanded Cell in IB]

Here is the source:

```
#define UITABLEVIEWCELLSIZE_COLLAPSED 97
#define UITABLEVIEWCELLSIZE_EXPANDED 285
#define EXPANDED 1
#define COLLAPSED 0

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSNumber *state = [cellExpansionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    if ([state intValue] == COLLAPSED) {
        return UITABLEVIEWCELLSIZE_COLLAPSED;
    }else if([state intValue] == EXPANDED) {
        return UITABLEVIEWCELLSIZE_EXPANDED;
    }
    return UITABLEVIEWCELLSIZE_COLLAPSED;
}

//expandCell is called when the arrow indicator is clicked on the cell
-(IBAction)expandCell:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger cellNumber = [sender tag];
    NSNumber *state = [cellExpansionArray objectAtIndex:cellNumber];
    if (state.intValue == 0) {
        [cellExpansionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:cellNumber withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXPANDED]];
    }else if (state.intValue == 1) {
        [cellExpansionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:cellNumber withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:COLLAPSED]];
    }
    //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
    //[self.tableView endUpdates];
    //[self.tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:cellNumber] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PCFCustomCell";
    PCFCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1slot.png"]]];
    PCFClassModel *course = [classesOffered objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    cell.courseCRN.text = [course CRN];
    cell.courseDataRange.text = [course dateRange];
    cell.courseDaysOffered.text = [course days];
    cell.courseHours.text = [course credits];
    cell.courseInstructor.text = [course instructor];
    cell.courseTime.text = [course time];
    cell.courseLocation.text = [course classLocation];
    cell.courseSection.text = [course sectionNum];
    cell.courseName.text = [course courseNumber];
    cell.courseTitle.text = [course classTitle];
    cell.courseType.text = [course scheduleType];
    //cell.professorEmail.text = [course instructorEmail];
    [cell.mailProf setTag:[indexPath section]];
    [cell.showCatalog setTag:[indexPath section]];
    [cell.followClass setTag:[indexPath section]];
    [cell.addToSchedule setTag:[indexPath section]];
    [cell.buttonDropDown setTag:[indexPath section]];
    [cell.mailProf setHidden:NO];
    [cell.mailProf setEnabled:YES];
        if (![course instructorEmail]) {
            [cell.mailProf setTitle:@"NO EMAIL PROVIDED" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.mailProf setEnabled:NO];
        }
    [cell.followClass setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_res_11.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.addToSchedule setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_res_09.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([savedResults count] > 0) {
        for (PCFClassModel *courseTwo in savedResults) {
            if ([[courseTwo CRN] isEqualToString:[course CRN]]) {
                [[cell followClass] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_activated.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //schedule
    if ([savedSchedule count] > 0) {
        for (PCFClassModel *courseTwo in savedSchedule) {
            if ([[courseTwo CRN] isEqualToString:[course CRN]]) {
                [[cell addToSchedule] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"purdue_activated.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [cell.mailProf addTarget:self action:@selector(mailProf:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.showCatalog addTarget:self action:@selector(showCatalog:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.followClass addTarget:self action:@selector(followClass:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.addToSchedule addTarget:self action:@selector(addToSchedule:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.buttonDropDown addTarget:self action:@selector(expandCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //get internet data
    /*
    [[cell staticAvailable] setHidden:YES];
    [[cell available] setHidden:YES];
    [cell.available setText:@""];
    [[cell remainingActivityIndicator] startAnimating];
    dispatch_queue_t getSpots = dispatch_queue_create("GetSpots", nil);
    dispatch_async(getSpots, ^{
        NSString *webData = nil;
        while (!webData && self.view.window) webData = [PCFWebModel queryServer:[course classLink] connectionType:nil referer:@"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec" arguements:nil];
        if (!self.view.window) return;
        NSArray *courseRecord = [PCFWebModel parseData:webData type:3];
        PCFCourseRecord *record = [courseRecord objectAtIndex:0];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cell remainingActivityIndicator] stopAnimating];
            [[cell staticAvailable] setHidden:NO];
            NSString *val = @"1";
            if ([val compare:record.enrolled] > 0) {
                //[[cell available] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            }else {
                //[[cell available] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.0565442 green:.430819 blue:.0724145 alpha:1]];

            }
            [[cell available] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SLOTS: %@/%@", record.enrolled,record.capacity]];
            [[cell available] setHidden:NO];
            [PCFAnimationModel fadeTextIntoView:cell.available time:1];
            [PCFAnimationModel fadeTextIntoView:cell.staticAvailable time:1];
        });
    });
    */
    // Configure the cell...
    //[PCFFontFactory convertViewToFont:cell];
    [cell.courseTitle setFont:[PCFFontFactory droidSansFontWithSize:13]];
    [cell.courseName setFont:[PCFFontFactory droidSansFontWithSize:38]];
    [cell.courseDaysOffered setFont:[PCFFontFactory droidSansBoldFontWithSize:11]];
    NSNumber *state = [cellExpansionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    if (state.intValue == COLLAPSED) {
        [cell.imageViewBackground setHidden:YES];
    }else {
        //[cell.imageViewBackground setHidden:NO];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Check My Question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/15245488/1603072

Comment: This didn't help as my cells expand/contract on a button tap

Comment: Forgetting the background picture, all of the items are bound to top and bottom, have you tried binding them to left/top?

Comment: You want to hide all the cells until you pressed the down arrow given on top? That is what you want to bring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an autosizing issue to me! Subviews of your cell have flexible margins & width,height. I can give few suggestions and not the exact solution. Hope they help..

1. Try removing the autosizing properties to subviews (In XIB click on view->goto Size inspector->Autosizing) OR
2. Create 2 different cell templates to be used during states expand and collapse. Same Cell XIB with 2 different cell views. Use UINib to load the xib.
3. Dont use pattern image as cell background if image is fixed size. Make use of  `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight` image API.

Cheers!
Amar.

Comment: I figured the issue out. I need to let the cell be at it's maximum size in IB instead of setting it to the lower size. For some reason if I expand it when it is in it's minimal height in IB it does it. If I leave it full size in IB and just change the height in code it works

Answer (score -1):

You haven't posted your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but I am guessing you are wrongly reusing cells there. Check the answer to a similar question:

[Objective C UITableView - Table cells display wrong content after changing cell's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080943/objective-c-uitableview-table-cells-display-wrong-content-after-changing-cell)

---

I tried with a code similar to yours and it seems to work as expected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    states = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        [states addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title @%d", indexPath.section];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Subtitle @%d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber *state = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [states replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!state.boolValue]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber *state = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    if (state.boolValue == false)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else
    {
        return 244;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't need to change anything in cellForRowAtIndexPath as the content is already in the cell and doesn't need to be changed. It is just below what can be seen by the user until the expand button is clicked. If you see the pictures I have attached you can see what I am referring to.

Comment: So you basically have a single cell prototype which you fill entirely when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called? The only difference is that you are changing the height of expanded cells?

Comment: Correct. The cell is entirely filled in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. The only thing done is the height is changed and the cell is being changed and I am calling reloadSections..

EDIT: I will include cellForRowAtIndexPath anyways

Comment: I have tried with the code similar to yours and it works. I suggest you simplify your code. My first guess is still `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :-). I can share the entire sample project if you wish.

Comment: There's literally nothing wrong with my cellForRowAtIndexPath. If I do zero configuration and leave the default text values, when the cell is expanded it still does not look properly. You can see the the cell expand into three separate grouped cells(yet very close/not with the same padding as the others).

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you with this one and asking one more dumb question. At the end of your method you hide the `imageViewBackground` but I can't find where you show it again? Should this image be used in any way?

Comment: The reason I left it hidden was to emphasize the fact that when I click the expand arrow, you can see three grouped table cells in total for that ONE cell. When everything works as normal I will unhide it  to make the layout look better for the rest of my elements.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will help your situation. But often if you want to animate reloading cells in a table after changing the height without doing reloads and suchlike, you can just do the following.

```
[tableview beginUpdates];
[tableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: Hey, I already tried a series of ways such as the one you posted, reloading the section in question, and reloading the whole table - none of which worked :(

Comment: Oh, you did too. Sorry i completely missed the bit that was commented out.